# Single variable to stand in for multiple key names - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array, something like this:

```
array =     
    [
        {
            "type": "apple",
            "color": "red",
            "id": "redApple"
        },
        {
            "type": "grape",
            "color": "green",
            "id": "greenGrape",
            "options": [
                {
                    "bunchName": "bunch1",
                    "size": "8"
                },
                {
                    "bunchName": "bunch2",
                    "size": "10"
                },
                {
                    "bunchName": "bunch3",
                    "size": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have a function that searches for values in the array.

```
function findValue (index, key) {
    return array[index][key];
}

var value = findValue(0, "id");
// returns redApple
```

Is there a way I could pass a single argument to the function if I wanted to find something deeper in the array?  For example, if I wanted to find `"bunchName"` could I pass it something like `1, "options[0].bunchName"` and get back `"bunch1"`?

I want a function that can handle multiple keys.  In my real project sometimes I'm looking for something on the first level, sometimes I'm looking on the second level, sometimes the third level, etc.

jQuery can be used if for some reason that would help.

Comment: please specify the wanted result by taking a path to an object with an array with objects.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Probably want to use a library like lodash to simplify this

Comment: please add the result if taken `'options.bunchName'` as parameter for the function.

Comment: Some libraries like Lodash can be used https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get. Otherwise, it can be done in JavaScript with recursion, loop, or maybe `eval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the string, replace the brackets, split the string and reduce the path for the result. The function uses a default object for missing or not given properties.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .replace(/\[/g, '.')
        .replace(/\]/g, '')
        .split('.')
        .reduce(function (o, k) { return (o || {})[k]; }, object);
}

function findValue(index, path) {
    return getValue(array[index], path);
}

var array = [{ type: "apple", color: "red", id: "redApple" }, { type: "grape", color: "green", id: "greenGrape", options: [{ bunchName: "bunch1", size: "8" }, { bunchName: "bunch2", size: "10" }, { bunchName: "bunch3", size: "5" }] }];
        
console.log(findValue(1, "options[0].bunchName"));
```

Comment: This was a good answer.  The only issue I had with it was that I do not want to use .reduce because of compatibility issues with older versions of IE.  But I was able to use this with a work around for the reduce portion of the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, output of findValue(object, "bunchName"); should be "bunch3", where object is array in OP's example.

```js
var object =
    [
        {
            "type": "apple",
            "color": "red",
            "id": "redApple"
        },
        {
            "type": "grape",
            "color": "green",
            "id": "greenGrape",
            "options": [
                {
                    "bunchName": "bunch1",
                    "size": "8"
                },
                {
                    "bunchName": "bunch2",
                    "size": "10"
                },
                {
                    "bunchName": "bunch3",
                    "size": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

var findValue = (object, key) => {
    var resultValue;
    var rec = (currentObj) => {
        if(currentObj && typeof currentObj === "object"){
            for(let curKey in currentObj){
                if (curKey === key){
                    resultValue = currentObj[curKey];
                }else{
                    rec(currentObj[curKey]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    rec(object);
    return resultValue;
}
console.log(findValue(object, "bunchName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function that takes an object and a key and returns `object[key]` and then split your key string into a list of individual keys by the dot. Then you could traverse the list of keys and use the function to get the value for each level in your object:

Totally untested code I just whipped up:

```
function valueByKey(obj, key) {
  if (obj) {
    return obj[key];
  }
}

function findValue(index, key) {
  const keys = key.split('.');
  let value = array[index];
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    value = valueByKey(value, keys[i]);
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-recurrent solution:

```
var array = [
    {
        'a': {
            'b': 1
        }
    }
];

function findValue(index, key) {
    var keys = key.split('.');
    var tmp = array[index];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (!tmp.hasOwnProperty(keys[i]) || typeof tmp !== 'object') {
            // throw an exception, or return default value – property not found.
        }
        tmp = tmp[keys[i]];
    }

    return tmp;
}

findValue(0, 'a.b');
```